# How to browse django psql backend from command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker, psql

I'm developing a website with Django 3 (in a docker container) using postgres sql as the backend; i.e. in the project settings file I have:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

I've populated the backend database and can browse the data using the admin. However, Id like to connect to the database via the command line so I can more easily test queries. I have tried connecting to the database the normal way from the command line:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \c postgres
```

The problem is that there is no data found:

```
postgres=# \dt
Did not find any relations.
```

Since I'm new to docker I thought to try connecting other ways as well; specifically, based on another post I tried:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5432 -t postgres/postgresql /bin/su postgres -c '/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf'
```

This throws an error:

```
pull access denied for psql/postgresql, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

Again, I'd like to connect to the database via the command line so I can more easily test queries. Perhaps Im on the right track but assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE, my docker-compose.yml file had the following service:

```
db:
        image: postgres:11
        volumes:
                - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

I am able to connect to the Django backend using the following command:

```
sudo docker-compose exec db psql -U postgres
postgres=# \c postgres
```

As suggested by @FlipperPA I will start useing a different username and database name

Answer (score 5):

It is a bad idea to use `postgres` for the database name, as there is a `postgres` database used for maintenance by default by PostgreSQL itself. I'd recommend calling the database something like `my_project`, then creating a service account user `my_project_user`, and assign a password:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# CREATE USER my_project_user WITH PASSWORD 'blahblah';
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE my_project WITH OWNER my_project_user;
postgres=# \q
```

Update your Django `DATABASES["default"]` settings accordingly, and run migrations. After running migrations, you can access your Django database using the following management command:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

You may be able to issue the command above with your current setup, but you may run into problems using `postgres` as your database name. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This command below runs(opens) **the command-line client for PostgreSQL** so that you can test queries:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```